# Eigenvectors of the 1d Laplacian in python - Why do I get different answers

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, python

Consider this code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.linalg as linalg

## Domain
L = 5
M = 50
dx = L/(M-1)
xx = np.linspace(0, L, M)


## Diff matrix
row0 = np.zeros(M)
row0[[-1, 0, 1]] = [1, -2, 1]
row0 /= dx**2
D = linalg.circulant(row0)

# Dirichlet BCs -- implicitly set boundaries to 0
D = D[1:-1, 1:-1]

# Use negative laplacian
D *= -1


## Eigenvalue decomposition
ews, evs = linalg.eigh(D)

# ews, evs = linalg.eig(D)
# ews = ews.real


## Plot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
modulation = np.cos(pi/dx * xx[1:-1])  # [-1, +1, -1, +1, ...]
for ev in evs.T[:3]:
    ax1.plot(xx[1:-1], ev)
    ax2.plot(xx[1:-1], ev*modulation)
ax1.set_title("Unmodulated")
ax2.set_title("Modulated by [-1, +1, -1, +1, ...]")
plt.show(block=False)
fig.tight_layout()
```

with the following output

[image]

Now, if I don't do `D *= -1` then the contents of the two panels are swapped (i.e. the modulation becomes necessary to recover the true eigenvectors).
But theoretically, the eigenvectors should not have changed. *So why do I get different answers*?

**Note1**: both the modulated and unmodulated eigenvectors pass the validation of comparing `ev` to `D @ ev`. But the eigenvectors are supposed to be unique (up to a scaling), so what gives?

**Note2**: The issue seems related to aliasing, since the modulation is by a high-frequency signal. But I can't fathom what that has to do with eigenvalue problems.

**Note3**: If I uncomment the use of the (general) `eig` function, then it does not matter whether `D *= -1` was done or not (the eigenvectors always require the modulation). Isn't the wide discrepancy of the output disconcerting for the "stability" of these routines? I mean, sure, as iterative methods, they depend on the initial guesses, but the problem seems well-posed and simple to me, but the output varies greatly.

**Note4**: this is not the same issue as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043273/numpy-eigh-function-with-proper-signs), as I take care to transpose the eigenvector matrix.

**Note5**: by modulation I mean that the original signal/vector/function gets (pointwise) multiplied by the other, as seen in the code (`ev*modulation`)

Comment: Please explain what you call "modulation" by [-1,+1,-1...] in mathematical terms : which action on your initial matrix ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I've added Note5 to explain it.

Comment: Can you please post a self-contained script that reproduces exactly the issue you describe? This will make it easier to tell whether it is simply a coding mistake.

Comment: Another possible issue is that the eigenvectors are listed in the opposite order when you multiply the matrix by -1. This would happen if the eigh function by default returns the eigenvalues in order from largest to smallest

Comment: Looks like modulating means you're flipping the sign of every element of each eigenvector. If that's the case the results look about right to me. Edit: hm, I think I understand what you're saying, but can't explain it.

Comment: In fact Mike Hawk has located the issue: you are displaying for some reason the final eigenvectors instead of the first ones...

Comment: You're quite right @MikeHawk and JeanMarie. I feel incredibly stupid right now, but thanks a lot! Feel free to put the comment in an answer that I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I had simply forgotten that I needed to sort the eigenvalues and vectors, whose order otherwise depends on the sign of the matrix operator and the choice of numerical routine.